# Can I reset a borrow of a local in a loop?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have a processing loop that needs a pointer to a large lookup table.
The pointer is unfortunately triply indirected from the source data, so keeping that pointer around for the inner loop is essential for performance.

Is there any way I can tell the borrow checker that I'm "unborrowing" the state variable in the unlikely event I need to modify the state... so I can only re-lookup the slice in the event that the `modify_state` function triggers?

One solution I thought of was to change data to be a slice reference and do a `mem::replace` on the struct at the beginning of the function and pull the slice into local scope, then replace it back at the end of the function — but that is very brittle and error prone (as I need to remember to replace the item on every return). Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
struct DoubleIndirect {
    data: [u8; 512 * 512],
    lut: [usize; 16384],
    lut_index: usize,
}

#[cold]
fn modify_state(s: &mut DoubleIndirect) {
    s.lut_index += 63;
    s.lut_index %= 16384;
}

fn process(state: &mut DoubleIndirect) -> [u8; 65536] {
    let mut ret: [u8; 65536] = [0; 65536];
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut data_slice = &state.data[state.lut[state.lut_index]..];
    for ret_item in ret.iter_mut() {
        *ret_item = data_slice[count];
        if count % 197 == 196 {
            data_slice = &[];
            modify_state(state);
            data_slice = &state.data[state.lut[state.lut_index]..];
        }
        count += 1
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Can you just pass `&mut state.lut_index` to `modify_state`?

Comment: The code about is a simplification...modify state calls tons of helpers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to ensure the borrows of `state` are all disjoint:

```
#[cold]
fn modify_state(lut_index: &mut usize) {
    *lut_index += 63;
    *lut_index %= 16384;
}

fn process(state: &mut DoubleIndirect) -> [u8; 65536] {
    let mut ret: [u8; 65536] = [0; 65536];
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut lut_index = &mut state.lut_index;
    let mut data_slice = &state.data[state.lut[*lut_index]..];
    for ret_item in ret.iter_mut() {
        *ret_item = data_slice[count];
        if count % 197 == 196 {
            modify_state(lut_index);
            data_slice = &state.data[state.lut[*lut_index]..];
        }
        count += 1
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is basically two things: first, Rust *will not* look beyond a function's signature to find out what it does.  As far as the compiler knows, your call to `modify_state` could be changing `state.data` as well, and it can't allow that.

The second problem is that borrows are *lexical*; the compiler looks at the block of code where the borrow *might* be used as goes with that.  It doesn't (currently) bother to try and reduce the length of borrows to match where they're *actually* active.

You can also play games with, for example, using `std::mem::replace` to pull `state.data` out into a local variable, do your work, then `replace` it back just before you return.

Comment: Is there a way to do the std::mem::replace in a try/finally-sort of block (maybe using RAII) ? The real code I'm working with has tons of returns all over?

Comment: @hellcatv Not really: that would imply giving the scope guard a mutable borrow of `DoubleIndirect` and, *oh look*, you're back to the original problem again.  You could wrap the "lots of returns" part of the function inside a closure, letting you "trap" said returns.

Comment: I ended up solving this by teasing out the parts of state that were modified in the modify_state function and placing those in a separate struct that was a member of my state struct.